# Name for a person who is awareness about an issue/subject

Tags: word-request

For example there is "observer" for somebody who professionaly follows a subject.
What about awareness? (I mean a word in the meaning of imaginary word "awareness+er")

Comment: A subject such as what? International relations or politics?

Comment: @Lambie. for example natural environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [afficionado](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/afficionado) is a person who likes, knows about, and appreciates a usually fervently pursued interest or activity.

An [amateur](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amateur) is one who engages in a pursuit, study, science, or sport as a pastime rather than as a profession.

An [enthusiast](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enthusiast) is one who is ardently attached to a cause, object, or pursuit, or one who tends to become ardently absorbed in an interest.

An [expert](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expert) is a person who has special skill or knowledge relating to a particular subject.

And a [maven](http://one%20who%20is%20experienced%20or%20knowledgeable) is one who is experienced or knowledgeable.

In my opinion the word "maven" is less usual in formal writing than the others.

If you follow those links you will find some sample uses of these words.

Answer (score 1):

"Observer" is not at all a normal word used to describe someone who professionally follows a subject. Normally this would be an "expert."  However, specific fields often have jargon to describe their professionals.  For example: watchdog, commentator, analyst.

Your question about awareness is less clear. Do you mean someone who follows a subject but not at a professional level?  Again it depends on what the subject is.  Some candidates are: fan, follower, enthusiast, watcher.

Comment: I mean the meaning 1.1 in the oxford living dictionaries https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/awareness

Comment: You should specify what subject they are aware of, at least generally.  Different words are used in different fields.

Comment: for example natural environment

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you mean to say that someone is

> **informed**

as in making an

> **informed decision**

The Wall Street Journal has a column called

> **The Informed Reader**

which covers trending topics to keep the reader up to speed on happenings.